# jQuery Tablesorter Filter 'Reset search' not resetting select menu's placeholder

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Been using jQuery Tablesorter and jQuery Tablesorter Filter [plugin](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html) on our company To-Do List, and it works excellently for the most part. The one issue I'm having is with the 'Reset search' button.

The 'Reset search' button does reset the results to remove all search filters, but the select menu's placeholder does not reset to its default. This is the sequence of events:

-Default placeholder: 'Select a value'
-Select an option in the select menu, such as 'Value #1'
-Reset filtered results using 'Reset search' button, results get reset, but placeholder remains 'Value #1'

Anything I'm missing to correct this? The [plugin's](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html) demo resets the select menu's placeholder when the 'Reset search' button is clicked.

```
jQuery
    $( '#todo-list' ).tablesorter( {
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {filter_reset : '.reset'}

$this->list .= '<thead><tr>';
    $this->list .= '<th id="checkbox-col" class="sorter-false filter-false"></th>';
    $this->list .= '<th id="item-col" data-placeholder="Enter search term">'.apply_filters( 'ctdl_heading_item', esc_html__( 'Item', 'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'</th>';
    /** @var $priority int */
    if ( $priority == 1 ) $this->list .= '<th id="priority-col">'.apply_filters( 'ctdl_heading_priority', esc_html__( 'Priority', 'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'</th>';
    /** @var $progress int */
    if ( $progress == 1 && CTDL_Loader::$settings['show_progress'] == 1 ) $this->list .= '<th id="progress-col">'.apply_filters( 'ctdl_heading_progress', esc_html__( 'Progress', 'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'</th>';
    /** @var $categories int */
    if ( $categories == 1 && CTDL_Loader::$settings['categories'] == 1 ) $this->list .= '<th id="category-col" class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Filter">'.apply_filters(
        'ctdl_heading_category', esc_html__( 'Expeditor',
        'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'</th>';
    if ( CTDL_PP ) $this->list .= '<th id="planner-col">'.apply_filters( 'ctdl_heading_planner', esc_html__( 'Post Planner', 'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'</th>';
    /** @var $assigned int */
    if ( $assigned == 1 && ( CTDL_Loader::$settings['assign'] == 0 && ( CTDL_Loader::$settings['list_view'] != 0 && CTDL_Loader::$settings['show_only_assigned'] == 0
            && ( current_user_can( CTDL_Loader::$settings['view_all_assigned_capability'] ) ) ) || ( CTDL_Loader::$settings['list_view'] != 0 && CTDL_Loader::$settings['show_only_assigned'] == 1 )
            && CTDL_Loader::$settings['assign'] == 0 ) ) $this->list .= '<th id="assigned-col" class="filter-select" data-placeholder="Filter">'.apply_filters( 'ctdl_heading_assigned',
        esc_html__( 'Assigned to', 'cleverness-to-do-list' ) ).'</th>';
```

Generated HTML for the table:

```
<tr class="tablesorter-filter-row">
    <!--The below <td> correctly resets to the placeholder "Enter search term" when the reset button is clicked-->
    <td>
        <input class="tablesorter-filter" type="search" placeholder="Enter search term" data-column="1" style="width: 98%;"></input>
    </td>
    <!--The below <td> does not reset to the placeholder "Filter" when the reset button is clicked-->
    <td>
        <div id="msdrpdd20_msddHolder" class="ddOutOfVision" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
            <select id="msdrpdd20" class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="2" tabindex="-1">
                <option value="">
                    Filter
                </option>
                <option value="Carlos">
                    Carlos
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="msdrpdd20_msdd" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" style="width: 56px;" tabindex="0"> … </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: whats the generated html for the table?

Comment: I don't see the element with a class name of `reset` in the above code; but basically all this reset button does is clear out all of the filters (i.e. sets all of the input/select values to an empty string). To better help, please report any javascript errors (press F12, go to console) and/or share a demo, or show the resulting HTML.

Comment: -Updated the OP to show the generated HTML.
-No errors in the console

Comment: Updated the OP again.